# After login shift to Home Page C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm tring to make action that after each login user switch to Home Page.
But I need to switch in `View/Car/Index`. I try to put just path but it doesn't work. Any idea? Here is my `AccountController`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Automarket.Models;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

namespace Automarket.Controllers
{

    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Account
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (OurDBContext db = new OurDBContext())
            {
                return View(db.userAccount.ToList());
            }
        }

        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(UserAccount account)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (OurDBContext db = new OurDBContext())
                {
                    db.userAccount.Add(account);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                ModelState.Clear();
                ViewBag.Message = account.Firstname + " " + account.Lastname + "Succesfully Registered: ";
            }
            return View();
        }
        // Login method
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult Login(UserAccount user)
        {
            using (OurDBContext db = new OurDBContext())
            {
                var usr = db.userAccount.Single(u => u.Username == user.Username && u.Password == user.Password);
                if (usr != null)
                {
                    Session["UserID"] = usr.Id.ToString();
                    Session["Username"] = usr.Username.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("Logged In ");

                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(" ", "Username or Password are incoorect");
                }
            }
            return View();
        }


        public ActionResult LoggedIn()
        {
            if (Session["UserID"] != null)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(UserAccount account)
        {
            using (OurDBContext db = new OurDBContext())
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.userAccount.Add(account);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            return View(account);
        }

        // List the details of user
       public ActionResult Details(int id=0)
        {
            using (OurDBContext db = new OurDBContext())
            {
                UserAccount user = db.userAccount.Find(id);
                if (user==null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                return View(user);
            }
        }

        // post method for Delete User
        public ActionResult Delete(int id =0)
        {
            using (OurDBContext db = new OurDBContext())
            {
                UserAccount user = db.userAccount.Find(id);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                return View(user);
            }
        }

        [HttpPost,ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id=0)
        {
            using (OurDBContext db = new OurDBContext())
            {
                UserAccount user = db.userAccount.Find(id);
                if (user==null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                db.userAccount.Remove(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            using (OurDBContext db = new OurDBContext())
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
                UserAccount user = db.userAccount.Find(id);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                return View(user);
            }
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Firstname,Lastname,Email,Username,Password,ConfirmaPassword")] UserAccount user)
        {
            using (OurDBContext db = new OurDBContext())
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(user);
        }

    }
}
```

Index View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Automarket.Models.UserAccount>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}



<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Register")

</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Firstname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Lastname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Username)
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Firstname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Lastname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ActionResult LoggedIn()
    {
        if (Session["UserID"] != null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

    }
```

I think you'll have to put the name of the view that you want to show in "return View("nameOfViewHere")".

Answer (score 0):

`return RedirectToAction("Index", "Car");`

You need to pass controllers name too as you calling from a different controller